# WPeC - Adding conditional logic to purchases

Tags: theme-development, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I need to add conditional logic to purchases.

ie – ***item a*** included for free with the purchase of **item b** or **item a** can be purchased individually for x amount.

Does anyone know if this functionality can be achieved through settings on the backend of WPeC.

Thanks Cam

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There isn't an out of the box solution for this in WP e-commerce.

But if your products are downloads you could simply add the file as a variation.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, unfortunately these are physical products with SKUs. Are you aware of any tutorials on this subject? cheers

Comment: Afraid not, don't know of a plugin either.